# PHP: using if when the second condition might not be set

Tags: php

A pretty simple question, I am wondering how php handles the use of IF and AND.

Say i have the following php code:

```
if ((pony) && (pony == 2)) {
  /* do something */
}
```

if pony is equal to 0, would the code still check if pony is equal to 2 or would it stop there?

Answer (score 3):

No. The boolean operators exhibit short-circuit behavior.  In other words, PHP stops evaluating as soon as it knows the result of the entire expression.

See the PHP docs on [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Answer (score 1):

[@Jonathon Reinhart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119527/jonathon-reinhart) is correct, while at the same time you must recognize that you are NOT required to create variables before use.

With that being said this will work:

```
if ($pony && $pony == 2) {
  /* do something */
}
```

Although, using [strict](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) errors in PHP you would need to ensure that (in your case) the variable `pony` is defined using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
if (isset($pony) && $pony == 2) {
  /* do something */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use $ to define variables..

```
$pony = 0;

if (($pony) && ($pony == 2)) {
  echo "yeah";
}
/* false */
```

The value will be true, if you change the value of $pony = 2;
Logically, nothing was tested during the first condition, its not even a condition.

```
if($pony){
}
```

If you change your condition to... where $pony must be 0 and 2 at the same time is impossible

```
if (($pony == 0) && ($pony == 2)) {
  echo "yeah";
}
```

If you are trying to check if $pony has a value, see Samuel Cook's answer, isset

```
if (isset($pony) && $pony == 2) {
  /* do something */
}
/* does $pony has a value/initiated AND its value must be 2 */
```